# How to accept floats as user input, without the dreaded infinite loop

Tags: c, types, floating-point, type-conversion

Ok, so this is homework for my c programming class. I'm just putting that out there. I'm looking for tips on revision. I reckon I could make it a lot more streamlined by using a switch for the isTriangle function. Stuff like that. I also need to add a function that determines area. I'm working on that now. :)

My big question, though, is: how can I allow for user input to be floats, without getting an infinite loop? I tried changing all of the relevant data types and scanf conversion types to float and %2.2f, respectively. The compiler gave me a ton of errors... suggesting that the function prototype didn't match the arguments. This code works well with integers only. I'm not asking anyone to write it for me, but maybe offer examples of where I could be going wrong? Also *any* advice on improving my code is appreciated.

I'm new to C, except for tweaking, and writing bash scripts (if that even qualifies), so if my code is very stiff and excessive, it's because I'm pretty uncomfortable working in it.

Thanks, guys!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//variable declarations


int test = 1; //global user bool 

//function delclarations

int isTriangle(int side1, int side2, int side3);
int kindOfTriangle(int side1, int side2, int side3);
int stayorGo();



//Intro and input in main
int main(){

    do{
        int side1, side2, side3;

        printf( "*********************Welcome to Triangle Wrangle!*********************\n");
        printf( "You will need to enter three integer values representing each side of your triangle.\n");
        printf( "Please enter the first side of your triangle, then hit enter.\n");
        scanf ("%d", &side1);
        printf( "Please enter the second side of your triangle, then hit enter.\n");
        scanf ("%d", &side2);
        printf( "Please enter the third side of your triangle, then hit enter.\n");
        scanf ("%d", &side3);

        isTriangle(side1, side2, side3); // is it a triangle?

    }while(test == 1);

} 



// does input pass the triangle smell test?
int isTriangle(side1, side2, side3){

//this should be written as a switch, to make code more readable/not shitty.
    if (side1 > side2 + side3  || side2 > side1 + side3 || side3 > side1 + side2 || side1 == 0 || side2 == 0 || side3 == 0){

            printf("Your triangle is not a true triangle!\n");

            stayorGo(); // start over or end program


    }else{

        kindOfTriangle(side1, side2, side3);
        printf("Lets talk about what kind of triangle this is.\n");
    }

}



int kindOfTriangle(side1, side2, side3){


    if((side1 == side2) && (side2 == side3) && (side1 == side3)){
        printf("*****This triangle is Equilateral. It is equal on all sides.*****\n");
        printf("\n");
        stayorGo();
    }else if (side1 == side2 || side2 == side3 || side1 == side3){
        printf("*****This triangle is Isosceles. It is equal on two sides.*****\n");
        printf("\n");
        stayorGo();
    }else if((side1 != side2) && (side2 != side3) && (side1 != side3)){
        printf("*****This triangle is Scalene. It has no equal sides.*****\n");
        printf("\n");
        stayorGo();
    }else{
        printf("You have managed to trick the program. It does not know what kind of triangle was input\n");
        printf("\n");
        stayorGo();
    }

}



// User prompt to end or continue
int stayorGo(){

    int keepTrying = 1;

    printf("Do you want to try again? 1 for yes, 0 for no; then hit enter!\n");
    scanf("%d", &keepTrying);

    if (keepTrying == 1){

        return 0;

    }else{

        exit(0);
    }
}
```

:::::::::Edit:::::::::

Here is the float code that is messed up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//variable declarations

int test = 1; //global user bool 

//function delclarations

float isTriangle(float side1, float side2, float side3);
float kindOfTriangle(float side1, float side2, float side3);
int stayorGo();



//Intro and input in main
int main(){

    do{
        float side1, side2, side3;

        printf( "*********************Welcome to Triangle Wrangle!*********************\n");
        printf( "You will need to enter three integer values representing each side of your triangle.\n");
        printf( "Please enter the first side of your triangle, then hit enter.\n");
        scanf ("%2.2f", &side1);
        printf( "Please enter the second side of your triangle, then hit enter.\n");
        scanf ("%2.2f", &side2);
        printf( "Please enter the third side of your triangle, then hit enter.\n");
        scanf ("%2.2f", &side3);

        isTriangle(side1, side2, side3); // is it a triangle?

    }while(test == 1);

} 



// does input pass the triangle smell test?
float isTriangle(side1, side2, side3){

//this should be written as a switch, to make code more readable/not shitty.
    if (side1 > side2 + side3  || side2 > side1 + side3 || side3 > side1 + side2 || side1 == 0 || side2 == 0 || side3 == 0){

            printf("Your triangle is not a true triangle!\n");

            stayorGo(); // start over or end program


    }else{

        kindOfTriangle(side1, side2, side3);
        printf("Lets talk about what kind of triangle this is.\n");
    }

}



float kindOfTriangle(side1, side2, side3){


    if((side1 == side2) && (side2 == side3) && (side1 == side3)){
        printf("*****This triangle is Equilateral. It is equal on all sides.*****\n");
        printf("\n");
        stayorGo();
    }else if (side1 == side2 || side2 == side3 || side1 == side3){
        printf("*****This triangle is Isosceles. It is equal on two sides.*****\n");
        printf("\n");
        stayorGo();
    }else if((side1 != side2) && (side2 != side3) && (side1 != side3)){
        printf("*****This triangle is Scalene. It has no equal sides.*****\n");
        printf("\n");
        stayorGo();
    }else{
        printf("You have managed to trick the program. It does not know what kind of triangle was input\n");
        printf("\n");
        stayorGo();
    }

}



// User prompt to end or continue
int stayorGo(){

    int keepTrying = 1;

    printf("Do you want to try again? 1 for yes, 0 for no; then hit enter!\n");
    scanf("%d", &keepTrying);

    if (keepTrying == 1){

        return 0;

    }else{

        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably better off posting your broken code using `float` than your working code using `int`.  That way we can see exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: I added the relevant code :)

Comment: `side1`, `side2`, `side3` are still declared `int` in your latest code.

Comment: I switched it back by hand. Sorry, the error is fixed now.

Comment: IT's still throwing a gagillion errors. Here is one:       lab1float.c: In function ‘kindOfTriangle’:
lab1float.c:60:11: error: argument ‘side1’ doesn’t match prototype
     float kindOfTriangle(side1, side2, side3){

Comment: And now your posted code simply has `float isTriangle(side1, side2, side3)` and `float kindOfTriangle(side1, side2, side3)`, neither of which have been valid-formatted C since K&R 25 years ago (and yours *isn't* K&R C). Nor does either function have a return value, though both declare one. Stop throwing up code. Take your time and post the *original* problem with the *correct* original code that produced it.

Comment: Unrelated: you should be checking that the side lengths are *positive*, rather than *non-zero*. Triangles can't have sides with negative lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function declarations do not match definitions.

In the `int` case they were tought to be `int` automatically:

```
int isTriangle(int side1, int side2, int side3);
/* .. */
int isTriangle(side1, side2, side3){
```

You introduced `float` only in declaration, but it remained `int` in definition:

```
float isTriangle(float side1, float side2, float side3);
/* .. */
float isTriangle(side1, side2, side3){
```

As functions do not `return` I modified footprint this way:

```
void isTriangle(float side1, float side2, float side3){
```

Perform same update on declaration as well and on kindOfTriangle function.
I also changed scanf argument from `"%2.2f"` to `"%f"` and it works fine for me.